# Maximum Nesting Level of 100 Reached, Aborting! - PHP

Tags: php, class

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\int\system\core\Controller.php on line 4

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  364608  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   1.0350  433152  Bootstrap->__construct( )   ..\index.php:11
3   1.0355  438536  Welcome->__construct( ) ..\Bootstrap.php:7
4   1.0355  438536  Controller->__construct( )  ..\welcome.php:4
5   1.0356  438680  View->__construct( )    ..\Controller.php:4
6   1.0356  438680  Controller->__construct( )  ..\View.php:4
```

Error line:

```
<?php
class Controller {
    function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View(); // Error starts here
        $this->model = new Model();
        $this->tpl = new Template();
        $this->input = new Input();
        $this->lib = new Library();
        $this->session = new Session();
    }
}
?>
```

How would I fix this? I tried extending the max nesting level, but everytime I increase it to lets say 200, it says fatal error maximum level of 200 reached, aborting!

Update: Fixed :)

```
public function __construct() {
        self::$instance =& $this;
        $this->view = new View;
        $this->model = new Model;
        $this->tpl = new Template;
        $this->input = new Input;
        $this->lib = new Library;
        $this->session = new Session;
    }
    public static function &get_instance() {
        return self::$instance;
    }
```

In model:

```
function __get($key)
{
    $fw =& Controller::get_instance();
    return $fw->$key;
}
```

Comment: I'd assume one of your loops went bad...

Comment: Figure out why the View constructor attempts to construct a Controller.

Comment: You have a circular reference between your `View` and `Controller`.

Comment: Well, I need it to be able to connect the $this->view, $this->model, etc. into views and models. The view+model controllers(and all else in that file) do not extend controller, but I want to be able to use them in view/model, so I attempted to extend the controller, it doesn't want to play nice I see.

Comment: As others suggested, this is a design issue. Have you considered other approaches? You're obviously running into a wall, why don't you simply remove the wall from equation?

Comment: When I remove the wall from the equation I run into another wall.

Comment: Didn't fix it. For some reason i can't call $this->session, etc. from inside models.

Comment: The only error I'm obtaining now is the fact when I do $this->session->{method}(); instead of returning like its supposed to, its echoing it out which I don't want it to.

Comment: aha, I'm an idiot sorry. I found out I put the same line of code into a model that was called and forgot to remove it. Hence  why it duplicated it. AHA sorry.

Answer (score 4):

That's because the constructor of `View` calls the constructor of `Controller` and vise versa. You need to refactor the code to remove that circular reference.

I personally see no reason why a view needs to create a controller or even needs to know about a controller. The control flow should being unidirectional: from the controller to the view.

If you need to inject functionality from controller into the view, you may assign callbacks to it. Like this:

```
class Controller {

    function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();
        $this->view->setFooFunction(function() {
            // do some stuff
        });
        echo $this->view->render();
    }

}


class View {

    protected $foo_function;

    public function __construct() {
        // ... no controller required :)
    }

    public function setFooFunction(Closure $function) {
        $this->foo_function = $function;
    }


    public function render() {
        $this->foo_function->__invoke();
        ... 
    }

}
```

Comment: The point behind it is to be able to use $this->view, $this->model, etc. from inside views and models. It works fine in controllers just not in views/models.

Comment: If your model communicates with the view, you have a serious design problem

Comment: It doesn't, but I want to be able to call the $this->{method} that controller has defined, for examle librarys, input, session, etc.

Comment: Anyway. You need to remove the `new Controller()` from  `View::__construct()`

Comment: I did remove it, but how do I call the $this->input for example?

Comment: Answer: Don't call `$this->input` from the view. You should [learn how the `MVC` pattern works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) before start coding.

Comment: I have learned it, however I would like to call it from the view/model. For example, codeigniter can call $this->input, etc. from the models and views and controllers, so why can't this?

Comment: I cannot help much further. I would suggest to have a deeper look into codeigniter's source code if you want your framework behaving like this.

Comment: I've done a __get() function, but on return of value from Class->model (in this case, model calls $this->session->userdata('test') to see if session 'test' exists), it echos out result even when not told to echo it, but return the value.